# I'm building an IP block system using PHP and mysqli but the system only blocks the IP in the first row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently building a simple IP block system:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "php";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT ip FROM blocked_adresses";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (in_array ($ip, $row)) {
    header("Location: block.html");
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

But the system only blocks the first row so it can only block one IP even though I can't see where I told it to choose the first row.

Comment: Please explain a bit what is an IP Block system? Your question mostly contains code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is as expected, since you only ever fetch one row at a time with `fetch_array`.

```
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM blocked_adresses";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If you wanted all the rows in the table into an array, you'd use [`fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead.

I have to wonder though, why not simply do a direct lookup on the actual IP address? Imagine when you have 10000 banned IPs in the table. Rather, you could simply do:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM blocked_adresses WHERE ip = '$ip' LIMIT 1";
...
```

Would that make sense, or is there something I'm missing re: your use case here?